# Regex pattern to validate -1,0,1,...9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

In my angular project, I'm validating a text box should accept only `-1,0,1,2,...9` using `Angular Directives` and `Regex`

The following code is accepting both positive and negative values. But I want to restrict that allow only -1 for negative value.

```
app.directive("onlyNumber", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            max: '=',
        },
        priority: 10,
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var oldVal = Number(element.val());
            element.bind('input', function(e) {
                var position = this.selectionStart - 1;

                //remove all but number and .
                var fixed = this.value.replace(/(?!^-)[^0-9.]/g, '');
                if (fixed.charAt(0) === '.') //can't start with .
                    fixed = fixed.slice(1);

                var pos = fixed.indexOf(".") + 1;
                if (pos >= 0) //avoid more than one .
                    fixed = fixed.substr(0, pos) + fixed.slice(pos).replace('.', '');

                if(maxLimits[e.currentTarget.name] != undefined ){
                    if(maxLimits[e.currentTarget.name]['decimal'] == "YES"){
                        if(fixed.indexOf('.') != -1){
                            if(fixed.length > (fixed.indexOf('.')+3))
                                fixed = fixed.substring(0, fixed.length-1);
                        }
                    } else{
                        fixed = fixed.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    }

                    if (this.value !== fixed) {
                        this.value = fixed;
                        this.selectionStart = position;
                        this.selectionEnd = position;                          
                    } else{
                        if(this.value > Number(maxLimits[e.currentTarget.name]['maxVal'])){
                            element.val(oldVal);
                        } else{
                            oldVal = Number(element.val());
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    if(e.currentTarget.attributes.getNamedItem('decimal').value == "YES"){
                        if(fixed.indexOf('.') != -1){
                            if(fixed.length > (fixed.indexOf('.')+3))
                                fixed = fixed.substring(0, fixed.length-1);
                        }
                    } else{
                        fixed = fixed.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                    }

                    if (this.value !== fixed) {
                        this.value = fixed;
                        this.selectionStart = position;
                        this.selectionEnd = position;                          
                    } else{
                        if(this.value > Number(e.currentTarget.max)){
                            element.val(oldVal);
                        } else{
                            oldVal = Number(element.val());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Regex:

```
this.value.replace(/(?!^-)[^0-9.]/g, '');
```

Can anyone tell me the proper `regex` that should allow only `-1` and positive values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are allowing decimal numbers too, I think. Aren't you?

Comment: You can try `(-1|[0-9]+)$`. Sample https://regex101.com/r/EjHjxb/2

Comment: `<input type="number" min="-1" max="9" step="1" />`

Comment: You have a `.` in the `[]` so you want to match the literral dot as if you were allowing decimal. May you clear this point?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following regex?

```
^(-1|[0-9])$
```

See it live on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xaloca/1)

---

If you want to allow any positive number, you can use the following regex:

```
^(-1|[0-9]+)$
```

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted? Looks like this suits OP's needs perfectly.

Comment: As per my code flow this is behaving opposite scenario. i.e, now the textbox allowing all the values except `-1,0,1,2..9`. Can you suggest the `IF_NOT` matches?

Comment: What would be the expected output if the value is wrong, e.g. -54? An empty string?

Comment: yes.. From this `/(?!^-)[^0-9.]/g` regex, its allowing all negative values(`-1,-2,-23, etc.,`). Can we restrict that it should accept only `-1` and any positive values?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3: Can you reply to my question?

Comment: @Ranjith How about `if(regex.test(string)) { ... } else { ... }` with the above mentioned regex?

Comment: Is there a way to put a not matching conditions in regex?.

Comment: You could use `^(?!^(-1|[0-9]+)$).+$` but I would just negate it in JavaScript as it is much more performing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this qualifies the answer.

```js
function check(val) {
  if (('' + val).split('.').length > 2) {
    return "Invalid Number";
  }
  try {
    val = parseFloat(val);
    if (-2 >= val) {
      return 'Invalid'; // this can be used for message or removing the input text value
    }
    return val; // you shouldn't return anything if valid as it will make the user input box flickery with cursor moving around.

  } catch (e) {
    return "Invalid Number";
  }
}

console.log(check(-1.2));

console.log(check(-2.000000001));

console.log(check(1.32143241239));

console.log(check(987654321));

console.log(check('1.32143.241.239'));
```

Comment: I need it using AngularJS only.

Comment: I have given the logic, to be used for validation. I think inside `element.bind` you are using javascript.